Recipient email not showing scanning QR code generated from python
I have tried to make a script as shown bellow.
The script works perfectly in every other way except that it does not generate re recipient in the "to" field. Any ideas why?
QR image generated added as well.
import qrcode
import os
import urllib.parse

# Define the mailto URL components
recipient = "my.email@example.com"
subject = "Fault report"
body = "The machine is broken. HEEELP!"

# Encode the subject and body
subject_encoded = urllib.parse.quote(subject)
body_encoded = urllib.parse.quote(body)

# Construct the mailto URL
mailto_url = f"mailto:{recipient}?subject={subject_encoded}&body={body_encoded}"

# Print the mailto URL for debugging
print(f"Mailto URL: {mailto_url}")

# Create QR code
qr = qrcode.QRCode(
    version=1,
    error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
    box_size=10,
    border=4,
)
qr.add_data(mailto_url)
qr.make(fit=True)

# Create an image from the QR Code instance
img = qr.make_image(fill='black', back_color='white')

# Save the image to a file
filename = "Fault_qr.png"
current_directory = os.getcwd()
file_path = os.path.join(current_directory, filename)

print(f"Current directory: {current_directory}")
print(f"Saving file to: {file_path}")

img.save(file_path)

print(f"QR code generated and saved as {filename}")


The script is supposed to generate a qr code that people can scan to report an error with a predetermined recipient email.QR error report

i think the issue is the QR code generation libraries typically don't modify the content of the URL they encode. They simply consider it as a string of data.
By giving complete mailto URL with the recipient, the encoded QR code data will contain all the necessary information for scanning and opening a new email with the desired recipient, subject, and body.
you can try this code.
import qrcode
import os

mailto_url = f"mailto:my.email@example.com?subject=Fault%20report&body=The%20machine%20is%20broken.%20HEEELP!"

print(f"Mailto URL: {mailto_url}")

qr = qrcode.QRCode(
    version=1,  # Adjust version for desired size and complexity
    error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,  # Error correction level
    box_size=10,  # Size of each box in the QR code
    border=4,  # Width of the border around the QR code
)

qr.add_data(mailto_url)  # Add the mailto URL as data
qr.make(fit=True)  # Ensure data fits within the QR code

img = qr.make_image(fill_color='black', back_color='white')  # Use descriptive color names

filename = "Fault_qr.png"
file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename)

print(f"Saving QR code as: {file_path}")

img.save(file_path)

print(f"QR code generated and saved as {filename}")


seems like the same issue remain. I'm starting to think it might have to do with policy restrictions since your solution seems to be close to the same as everyone elses I've read online
